# Variable won't store in session

Tags: php, session, pdo, session-variables

So I'm trying to store the "rank" of a user when they log in to a control panel which displays different options depending on the given rank. I used the same method as I did for storing and  displaying the username, which is displayed on the top of each page and works just fine. I can't for the life of me figure out why it won't work for the rank value, but I do know that it is not saving it in the session. Here is the bit that's not working;

```
$username = ($_POST['username']);
$password = hash('sha512', $_POST['password']);

$dbhost = 'mysql:host=██████████████████████;dbname=███████████';
$dbuser = '███████████';
$dbpassword = '████████████████';

try {
$db = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$statement = $db->prepare("select password from users where email = :name");
$statement->execute(array(':name' => $username));
$result = $statement->fetch();
$pass = $result[password];
$rank = $result[rank];}

catch(PDOException $e) {echo $e->getMessage();}

if ($password == $pass) {

session_start();
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['rank'] = $rank;
header('Location: http://█████████.ca/manage.php');

}
else{
include'../../includes/head.inc';
echo '<h1>Incorrect username or password.</h1>';
include'../../includes/footer.inc';
}
```

I'm also new to the whole PDO thing, hence why my method of authenticating the password is pretty sketchy.

Comment: Oh, there's our Mittens.  We've been missing them.

Comment: Don't forget to call `exit` after your `header('Location: ...')` calls! Otherwise the code will continue to run after the header call and be visible to hackers!

Comment: ThiefMaster, I think it is distracting :-/

Comment: Thank for the tip Emil, will add that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not that it doesn't save the rank - apparently you do not retrieve it from
the query. You only ask for the password. The username comes from elsewhere:

```
$db = new PDO($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpassword);
$statement = $db->prepare("select password from users where email = :name");

// Should be select password, rank

$statement->execute(array(':name' => $username));
$result = $statement->fetch();
$pass = $result[password];
$rank = $result[rank];}
```

Comment: Also, it wouldn't hurt to properly quote array indices, e.g. `$pass = $result['password'];` and `$rank = $result['rank'];`

Comment: I knew it  was going to be some silly little mistake, haha. Thanks very much for the help, making progress now!